# Bigger space between letters in one position in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

For implement spacing it i used

> `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

But in this case I need control a lot of different things for keeping right format. For example if user put cursor between 1 and 2 and add new digit. Or remove digit 1.

How can I set bigger spacing between of certain symbols?
Customise `UITextField` by some way for example.

[image]

UPD: I implemented `NSMutableAttributedString`, but when I use it this way, cursor moves in the end of string each time when I put symbols in center of text. So probably it is not right place to put this code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
NSString *futureString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
if(textField == phoneNumberTextField){
    if(futureString.length>=2){
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:futureString];
        [attributedStr addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:@(5)
                              range:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
        phoneNumberTextField.attributedText = attributedStr;
        return NO;
    }else
        if(futureString.length > 10){
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
```

}

Comment: Use onChange event and edit string by adding spaces between numbers

Comment: You could use `NSAttributedString` and `NSKernAttributeName`.

Comment: Yuri, I don't want to add extra symbols. I want make bigger distance between symbols.

Comment: look at https://github.com/Serheo/SHSPhoneComponent It uses shouldChangeCharactersInRange event. May be it is only one way to do it.

Comment: Larme, I tryed to use NSAttributedString and NSKernAttributeName. I think it looks like solution. But where is the best place to use it?

Comment: I don't know, I've never use it really. You may have to do some tries with a string of length 5, and see what happens if you put it on only one, at the start, middle, or end, at two consecutive chars, two non-consecuvite chars etc...